# How to show the folding commands in the Command Palette?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to have the folding commands to show up on the Command Palette? It'd be quite useful as opposed to have to remember all of them.

Comment: Hm, I'm pretty sure they used to show up there in previous VSCode versions...

Comment: I see lots of folding commands in the CP, which commands are you looking for specifically.

Comment: @Mark where? I search for "fold" and nothing comes up

Comment: Ctr-Shift-P `fold` and I get 16 different fold and unfold commands.  Are you using some language that doesn't have built-in folding support?  And no extension for it in that language?  Otherwise, sounds like a bug.

Comment: I was actually trying on a Javascript file. Strange enough, today I see the fold commands. I'm not sure what happened. Intelisense was acting very strange as well by autocompleting commands without my approval. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CTRL+K,CTRL+R and it will open a new browser tab with all the commands in a pdf file.

It will open this link as for today : "https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf"

I hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks for this shortcut, I wasn't aware of it.